# Distinguishing the design for LandscapeLeft and LandscapeRight in Xcode's storyboard's size classes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistoryboard, size-classes

I see how I can use size classes to change the constraints in a storyboard in Xcode so that the layout of my app differs in portrait and landscape orientations on an iPhone. But there are two different landscape orientations: `UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft` and `UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIDeviceOrientation)). How do I use size classes in the storyboard to distinguish the layout in these two different landscape orientations, for example aligning a view to the left of its container in one and to the right of its container in the other?